# Comment section gone after posting a comment on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

Just after posting a comment, the whole comment section gone.

Refreshing the post (by pull-to-refresh) didn't fix it, and I had to reopen the question to get it back.

(Steps to repro/condition to occur is not yet known)

Screenshot (after posting [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278398/it-is-about-time-to-update-the-about-time#comment902405_278398))

[image: no comment section]

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: Nexus 5

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (2704746)

Comment: Maybe just a connection hiccup on your side: as far as I know, after posting a comment, only the comments section is reloaded. So maybe the request to the server failed, leaving it empty. Though it does not explain why still empty after full refresh.